# how to extract DC coefficients of each block after partitioning into 8*8blocks?

Tags: matlab

I need to know that what should I do to get the exact value of DC coefficient of each block that was already partitioned into 8*8 blocks so that it can be stored into a new matrix in MATLAB.

While image compression using Discrete Cosine Transform, we divide the image into 8*8 non-overlapping partition. Now the task is to get DC coefficients on each block and collect these coefficients to put into a separate matrix so that I can manipulate some logic on image.

What should I do to get these coefficients?

```
x=imread('sec.png');
[r,c]=size(x);
DF=zeros(r,c);
N=8;

for i=1 : N : r
 for j=1 : N : c
        f = x(i:i+N-1,j:j+N-1);
        df =dct2(f);
        DF(i:i+N-1,j:j+N-1)=df;          
    end
end
```

Comment: anyone online here or just ignored my question or just say stackoverflow never help  others

Comment: Your Q is on hold , no one can answer it till you edit it to better Q.